# Unable to execute Jbehave stories via maven command line

Tags: maven, jbehave, jbehave-maven-plugin

[image]I want to execute my jbehave tests via mvn command line

I tried with below command but it is not picking up my story file for execution

here is the pom.xml file wherein I have configured Jbehave maven plugin still no luck

What is it am missing can anyone help?

Maven command tried
mvn clean test -Dspring.profiles.active=stage,chrome -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\Users\e090406.cache\selenium\chromedriver\win64\119.0.6045.105\chromedriver.exe" -Dthread.count=3 -Dstory=TC2649754.story

mvn clean test -Dspring.profiles.active=stage,chrome -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\Users\e090406.cache\selenium\chromedriver\win64\119.0.6045.105\chromedriver.exe -Dmeta.filter="+TC2649754"

It does not pick the test via command line .please refer attached image

**POM.xml**

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.7.4

com.mastercard.installments
installmentUI
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
installmentUI
Automation Suite for Installment UI

<java.version>11</java.version>
2.7.4-->
<maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
<junit.jupiter.version>5.9.3</junit.jupiter.version>
<selenium.version>4.14.1</selenium.version>
<webdrivermanager.version>5.5.2</webdrivermanager.version>
<cucumber.version>7.14.0</cucumber.version>
<cucumber.reporting.version>5.7.6</cucumber.reporting.version>
<maven.surefire.plugin>3.1.2</maven.surefire.plugin>
<lombok.version>1.18.30</lombok.version>
<jbehave.version>5.1</jbehave.version>
<allure.version>2.20.0</allure.version>
<allure.maven.version>2.10.0</allure.maven.version>
<allure.cmd.download.url>
https://artifacts.mastercard.int/artifactory/maven-all/io/qameta/allure/allure-commandline
</allure.cmd.download.url>
<junit.surefire.version>1.2.0</junit.surefire.version>
<maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>

-->
-->
-->

org.springframework.boot-->
spring-boot-dependencies-->
${springboot.version}-->
pom-->
import-->
-->
-->
-->

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>${webdrivermanager.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Cucumber dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.reporting.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--Jbehave dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jbehave.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${jbehave.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbehave.site</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-site-resources</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <!--Jbehave dependency to beautify report-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbehave.site</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-site-resources</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>


    <!--Hamcrest dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--AssertJ dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.24.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--Jackson dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--gson dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Epam jbehave portal-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.epam.reportportal</groupId>
        <artifactId>agent-java-jbehave</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.epam.reportportal</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-common</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.epam.reportportal</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-model</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.epam.reportportal</groupId>
        <artifactId>client-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.22</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Apache poi dependencies-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Rally API dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rallydev.rest</groupId>
        <artifactId>rally-rest-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!--Junit5 dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Lombok dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--Browser stack dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>browserstack-local-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Allure report dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Allure jbehave reporter dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.tapack</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-jbehave-reporter</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.surefire.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportFormat>plain</reportFormat>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        **<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jbehave.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>run-stories-as-embeddables</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/RunStories.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <systemProperties>
                            <property>
                                <name>java.awt.headless</name>
                                <value>true</value>
                            </property>
                        </systemProperties>
                        <ignoreFailureInStories>true</ignoreFailureInStories>
                        <ignoreFailureInView>false</ignoreFailureInView>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run-stories-as-embeddables</goal>
                        <goal>unpack-view-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-view-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>**
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How to run these jbehave stories using meta filter via command line?